# Multithreading, DataReaders & Bulk Inserts... Can this app be multithreaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, multicore, bulkinsert

Is it possible to extract the code section inside my code and have it run in multiple threads?

The app copies over data from a FoxPro db to our SQL server over a network (the files are quite huge so the bulk copy needs to happen in increments...

It works, but I'd like to bump up the speed a bit.

1) By either having the section I marked run in multiple threads, OR as an alternative,

2) not loop through each column in the datarow,

I went for the second option...  (Updated code below)

**CODE**

```
private void BulkCopy(OleDbDataReader reader, string tableName, Table table)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CopyData"]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tableName + " BulkCopy Started.");
            try
            {
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                foreach (Column col in table.Columns)
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add(col.Name, ConvertDataTypeToType(col.DataType));
                }

                int batch = 1;
                int counter = 0;

                DataRow tblRow = tbl.NewRow();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    counter++;                  
 ////This section changed
                        object[] obj = tblRow.ItemArray;
                        reader.GetValues(obj);
                        tblRow.ItemArray = obj;
////**********
                    tbl.LoadDataRow(tblRow.ItemArray, true);

                    if (counter == BulkInsertIncrement)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(tableName + " :: Batch >> " + batch);
                        counter = PerformInsert(tableName, tbl, batch);
                        batch++;
                    }
                }

                if (counter > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tableName + " :: Batch >> " + batch);
                    PerformInsert(tableName, tbl, counter);
                }

                tbl = null;
                Console.WriteLine("BulkCopy Success!");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BulkCopy Fail!");
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(tableName + " BulkCopy Ended.");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I went for the second option

I wasn't aware that while inside the while(reader.Read()) loop that i could do the following. I't helped to greatly increase the apps performance

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  object[] obj = tblRow.ItemArray;
  reader.GetValues(obj);
  tblRow.ItemArray = obj;
  tbl.LoadDataRow(tblRow.ItemArray, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're after, but have you tried running the console application in release mode first, with just one try statement, and using indexes on the reader? It's probably not going to increase the speed a great deal by making it multi-threaded as SQL Server will be the main bottleneck.

Of course if you don't care too much about data integrity (for example your IDs aren't sequential) you could change the [table locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) type for inserts and spin up 3-4 threads to read from certain points in the table.

Comment: I'll def try all your suggestions, as a point of interest, would you be able to supply a code sample as to how to change the table locking type, from withing c#.. I'ts literally the first I heard of it now, so seems a bit space age :p (I'll consult google as well)

Answer (score 4):

Thre is no need to multithread if you take out the beginner mistakes you do. TONS of slow code everywhere.

> tblRow[col.Name] = reader[col.Name];

SLOW. NEVER use name - get the index outside the loop, then use the indices. This line has 2 (!) dictionary lookups for eery row, taking more time than the row procesing.

DataTables / DataSet is dead slow to start with (bad trechnological choice) but code like that really slowy dou down. Use a profiler to see the other bad elements.

Comment: I'm aware of the sloppy-ness of it, although I didnt know that indexes would give a performance benefit, so thank you, I'll try it out now... And as for the datatables, SqlBulkCopy only allows for datatables, datarows & datareaders(which i couldnt use, as some of the records cause the whole transaction to fail), it would have been my first option...

Comment: +1 for sorting out smaller optimizations first. It may be that you find that you don't need to use multithreading if you can get the single-thread version faster to begin with

Comment: Ok, updated my code to use the indexes, performance pretty much the same, I forgot to mention that im doing a bulk insert of 20 000 records in each pass, +/- 5mil records per table & 60 odd tables... so i know performance over the network prob wont be amazing... thats why in my mind it seemed like the way to go was to have the adding of the records to the datatable occur in multiple threads... again, the dataset wasnt my first choice/route i took... bulk insert seemed like the way to go, so i took it to get the job done...

Comment: *And as for the datatables, SqlBulkCopy only allows for datatables, datarows & datareaders* - yes, which is why I use SqlBulkCopy over objects, you know. DatReaders = IDataReader, implement an ObjectDataReader (about 2 hours of work) and you are fine. I do 75.000 row inserts per second with 3 writer threads from one reader thread. I do not use a DataTable but objects and my own ObjectDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your usecase will significantly benefit from a parallel for each. Also it would be pretty hard to implement cause of the OleDbReader that is used in you code.

But what you could do is Schedule the inserts on a new thread that your loop will not block for the time the SQL Server needs to insert your data.

You can use the `Task.Factory.StartNew()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx) for this. But this will make error handling a bit more complex, in terms that when the insert fails you might have processed more data or in the worst case there is already another thread waiting with new inserts for the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4, you could try using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) , and convert the foreach loop into something like

```
Parallel.ForEach(table.Columns, col => {/*rest of function here */}
```

Comment: Sadly that leaves the main problem totally ignored - you can not paralellize that ad infinitum.